# Could not load file or assembly 'App_Licenses' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied

Tags: asp.net, iis, licensing

Has anyone ever come across this?  I've never seen it before.  I know there is a *.lic" file in my bin for some web charting software.

I did a publish, copied to dev server and then suddenly boom, get this error on every page.

Any ideas?  I've cleared out temp asp.net files and restarted IIS.

edit:

wow, I'm thinking this might be the TumbleWeed badge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the NETWORK SERVICE lost it's permission to the bin directory.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation>
            <buildProviders>
                <remove extension=".lic"/>
                <add extension=".lic" type="System.Web.Compilation.ForceCopyBuildProvider"/>
            </buildProviders>
         </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error and tried giving full rights to "Everyone" on bin folder but didn't solve problem. I was using VS2010 on windows 7. Running visual studio as administrator solved my problem.